# colocar cor em um <a>

Tags: html, css

Boas,

Estou em ter um problema em um menu que estou a criar, eu consegui tirar o sublinhado do texto que está definido como link mas eu queria mudar a cor para tornar um texto mais normal...
Alguem sabe como trocar a cor da letra de um ?

```css
ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-secundario {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1280px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-secundario li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;  
    color: black;
}

a:link {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-secundario">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Historias</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Linha temporal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Impacto da poluição</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Percurso</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Jogo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Imagem de como estão as letras no momento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que acontece se adicionar o `color: <cor>` no seu CSS onde personaliza os links? E o que o `:link` em `a:link` significa?

Comment: se meter o color no a:link a cor fica igual, e eu nao sei o que é o a:link eu simplesmente tentei tiraro sublinhado e isso assim funcionou entou eu deixei estar

Comment: Então recomendo que comece buscando entender o código que fez, pois sem saber o que já fez não terá como saber o que precisará fazer. Pesquise o que o `:link` faz e veja se faz sentido fazer desta maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação [MDN | Estilizando Links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Styling_links) existem pseudo-classes destinada exclusivamente para estilizar links em seus respectivos estados.

São esses os estados nos quais os links podem existir:

> - Link (não visitado) : o estado padrão em que um link reside, quando
>     não está em nenhum outro estado. Isso pode ser estilizado
>     especificamente usando a pseudo classe `:link`.
> - Visitados : um link
>     quando já foi visitado (existe no histórico do navegador), estilizado
>     usando a pseudo classe `:visited`.
> - Passe o mouse : um link ao passar o
>     mouse sobre o ponteiro do mouse de um usuário, estilizado usando a
>     `:hover`.
> - Foco : Um link quando ele foi focado (por
>     exemplo, movido para um usuário do teclado usando a tecla TAB ou
>     similar, ou programaticamente focado usando `HTMLElement.focus()`) - é
>     estilizado usando a pseudo classe `:focus`.
> - Ativo : um link quando está
>     sendo ativado (por exemplo, clicado), estilizado usando a pseudo classe
>     `:active`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.menu-secundario {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1280px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-secundario li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-secundario">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Historias</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Linha temporal</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Impacto da poluição</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Percurso</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Jogo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```